# How to create a youtube like preview of video?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

[image]How to create a youtube like video preview? That is in youtube, it is showing the preview of the video when we mouseover the progress bar? How to do that kind of preview using ffmpeg or mencoder or is there any other way to do that? Have a look at this image. Please go here for a live preview.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yto4_QFoLdA&feature=watch-now-button&wide=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/) extension. Below is some ancient code that I wrote to choose six thumbnails from a video.

The notable parts are:

```
$frame = $vid->getFrame(); // pull a frame from the video
$gd = $frame->toGDImage(); // turn the frame into a GD image
imagejpeg($gd, "filename.jpg", 70); // save jpeg of the frame using 70% quality
```

---

```
$vid = new ffmpeg_movie ( $fileName );
$frameRate = $vid->getFrameRate ();
$gapSize = max(10,$vid->getDuration()-10) * $frameRate / 6;
$n = 0; $curFrame = 5 * $frameRate;
while ( $n != 6 ) {
    $f = $vid->getFrame ( $curFrame );
    if ((1==$curFrame && false!==$f) || false !== ($f = $vid->getNextKeyFrame ())) {
        $thumbnails [$n] = array (
            'path' => "muveethumb-$muveeId-$n.jpg", 
            'time' => ceil ( ($vid->getFrameNumber () - 1) * 1000 / $frameRate ) 
        );
        $gd = $f->toGDImage ();
        imagejpeg ( $gd, $targetFolder.$thumbnails [$n] ['path'], 70 );
        ++ $n;
        $curFrame += $gapSize;
    } elseif ($n > 0) {
        while ( $n != 6 ) {
            $thumbnails [] = $thumbnails [$n - 1];
            ++ $n;
        }
    } else {
        if ($curFrame!=1) {
            // attempt to get first frame as a last resort
            $curFrame = 1;
        } else {
            // unless we already tried that
            throw new Exception ( "Could not create thumbnails" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is how i am doing now. But in case of youtube, they are showing the preview for every second. But i am not thinking that they are creating a preview for every second. They should use some other way to do that. Don't you think so?

Comment: @Udhay I'm actually not sure what you mean by that; I've never seen YouTube showing me anything when I hover over the progress bar; it just shows the time stamp ... once clicked, I see the video from that point onwards

Comment: @Udhay there's no other way than just changing the density and brute force it, creating many low-res caps :) I suppose you could optimize the process by stuffing them into a sprite, but other than that I don't think you can take any shortcuts.

Comment: ffmpeg also has the `select` filter which can select frames and pass them to the output.